# Add content on apache localhost

Tags: html, css, apache, web, localhost

I'm new to Web Development, and intermediately skilled in Linux. My current setup is CrunchBang 11 & I use Geany as my Text Editor. I'm learning how to make websites, got a sample code and I'm playing around with it. It consists of an index.html, main.html, a few css files and  jQuery file. I've made a Project Hearth.geany containing all the files.

I've setup LAMP Stack on my laptop (Dell Latitude D630) following instructions in http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server

I want to know how I add these content (the whole project) to work on my localhost so I can see it live.

I researched and I was told to add content to a folder called htdocs, the folder was located in my home directory. But, I still cannot see the content.

I want to be able to do something like type `localhost/project` on my web browser and it should show my website

Comment: If the folder is **reachable** anyone can hit the page and its contents.  That will depend on the network.  To move forward, read about some server side options.  ROR is a good place to start learning REST web applications.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you just said. What do you mean by a folder being reachable? Is there a specific place I need to put the above files into so apache can see them? I want to be able to do something like localhost/project on my web browser and it should show my website.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your 'project' inside ' /var/www ' folder ( it is the web root in the local machine ), then you can access it via localhost/project

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot add the whole project folder in '/var/www' and get it to work. I can copy all the files in the project to '/var/www' but then I will not be able to distinguish subsequent projects from this one. I hope I was clear.

Comment: may be you have permission issues. Try giving the permission to the www folder. sudo chown [user] /var/www

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think this post is more suited for the https://serverfault.com/ site, not this, so please move it.

Your web site should sit at the web site root, which in your setup should be

*/var/www/*

This can be verified by looking at the apache configuration files and searching for the 'DocumentRoot' directive.

This could be in either :

- /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
- /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
- /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

(You will have to do some searching).

As an example, on my test machine

```
$ cd /etc/apache2
$ grep -r DocumentRoot
sites-available/default:    DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that.